# Can we add charts for site statistics?

Tags: feature-request

Please provide charts showing trends in:

1) page views

2) number of users

3) [The length of our tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Tail). (Percent of page views by bottom %80 of least active users)

These charts would have similar look and feel as those currently provided on user reputation page.

**Justification**: we need a way to measure effectiveness of our efforts to increase site traffic.

Comment: Kirk, you might be interested in the data being posted [at another site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-are-we-doing-post-your-favorite-stats).  I haven't checked to see whether a similar thing could be done for GIS@SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moderators have access to these charts (and more, and always have).  We are specifically requested *not* to share details ("analytics data is intended for moderators only; please don't share the specifics of this data in public").  However, meta questions judiciously asking for summary information probably could be answered by a mod without violating this trust.

FYI, we get daily and averaged statistics on

```
Questions and Answers
Voting
Question vs. Answer Votes
New Users
Total Page Views
Number of Visits
Number of New Visits
Suggested Edits
Edits
Feedback by low rep. and anonymous users
Closed and Deleted Posts
Newsletter Subscriptions
```

and we can filter them by date ranges.

Comment: Well, I was going to suggest that this can be done using [http://data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com). But when I go to that it crashes IE8. See the announcement [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/).

Comment: You might want to add that behavior to your question about no scrollbar with IE8.  Yes, I believe you can get some of the statistics you want with the API, but many of them are not likely to be available (such as page views, visits, etc.).